# Can a low level wizard use a Staff of Power to cast higher level spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, caster-level

Is there any limitation on lower level wizards (say 1-8) from using a Staff of Power to cast higher level spell effects such as Wall of Force?  Is any kind of Arcane or use magic item roll required such as for spells on higher level scrolls?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**There is no limitation.**

The Staff of Power does exactly what it says on the lid. The only requirements is that it must be attuned by a wizard, sorcerer or warlock - level is irrelevant.

Of course, why a very rare magic item is in the hands of a such a low level character is another question.

Comment: I thought editing your answer to get around the question title/body mismatch was less work than fixing the question.